# What are the Features to add in a Server for deploying an ASP.Net MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, windows-server-2012

I am trying to host an MVC 4 web application in Windows Server 2012.

What are all the Features to be added for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to install iis for adding server roles and make sure asp .net is checked for role service.

Follow below step by step tutorial

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/installing-iis-8-on-windows-server-2012

Comment: but I was getting server error after steps in the link .. and ASP.Net also

Comment: can you get the detail error code by setting as the link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/05/25/iis7-how-to-enable-the-detailed-error-messages-for-the-website-while-browsed-from-for-the-client-browsers.aspx

also, a dumb question, can you make sure that the website runs on your local machine ( by that I mean from visual studio)

Comment: got the solution!! issue was the .Net framework was not registered with IIS  [(Command Line) as Administrator] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -r

Comment: Wow, no offence as I know you didn't make it, but that tutorial is _atrocious_. It could be summarised as 'Open add features, select IIS, click Next until the dialogs stop appearing'. Even the screenshots only show you a tiny bit of the useful information, i.e. what's actually being installed.

Answer (score 2):

you should install IIS with following features

ASP.NET 3.5+ should be installed if oyu don'thave WCF services you can not check the WCF or Widnows Communicaiton foundation features

Over **IIS**
you need to tick Applicaition Development features  ( ASP ASP.net and etc )
Common HTTP Features
and in the security seciton choose the security modules that you'll use

Comment: The "Application Development" piece is what I think is over real interest here and is certainly what was missing from my install. If you need more info on it, here's an official source that goes a lot more in depth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-1-install-iis-and-asp-net-modules